Sorting Names from rows of one sheet to another
Sheet1 list names of workers
Sheet3 list names of clients followed by names of the workers who worked with them.
I want it where if the workers name is in one of the following columns of sheet3 to show the clients name behind theirs on sheet1

For example
sheet 1
Sheet 1 (formula should go in cell B1)




A
B




1
Jhon
(f-x.)


2
Mark




sheet 3




A
B
C




1
Andy
Jhon
Mark



Desired output
Sheet 1 (formula in cell B1)




A
B




1
Jhon
Andy


2
Mark
Andy



Sheet 3 (no changes)




A
B
C




1
Andy
Jhon
Mark




Can you revise your example tables into markdown? You can use this Table to Markdown page to automate it for you.

Assuming the data in Sheet3!A1:E is like this:



Client
Workers







Andy
Jhon
Mark A.




Alice
Mark A.
Sine
Jhon
Eve


Amanda
Eve
Mark A.
Mark B.



Akira
Jill
Jhon
Mark A.




Put this formula in cell Sheet1!B1:
=let( 
  names, byrow(Sheet3!B1:Z, lambda(row, "_" & join("_", row) & "_")), 
  map(tocol(A1:A, 1), lambda(name, 
    torow(filter(Sheet3!A1:A, search("_" & name & "_", names))) 
  )) 
)

...to get this:



Worker
Clients







Jhon
Andy
Alice
Akira



Mark A.
Andy
Alice
Amanda
Akira


Eve
Alice
Amanda




Jill
Akira





Sine
Alice





Mark B.
Amanda






See
let(),
byrow(),
map(),
filter(),
search()
and
torow().
